# Moving the PostgreSQL data corresponding to a single table on another disk when pgdata is a docker volume

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a PostgreSQL database with one table having especially large amount of geographic data.

Because of that, I'm facing this kind of error today:

```
FATAL:  could not write lock file "postmaster.pid": No space left on device
```

The database is dockerized on a virtual machine. And the PG data is mounted as a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose).

Is it possible to move the underlying data file(s) corresponding to *only* this large table to another hard disk (I know I can move the entire PG data directory, which is a docker volume in that case, elsewhere but this is not exactly what the question is about), let's say a shared drive with much more place than the host drive on which the database currently is?

If yes, how could I achieve that?

PG version is 13 based on [postgis/postgis:13-3.1-alpine](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/tags)

**EDIT:**
The problem is that my postgres service in my docker composition relies on a volume managed by docker itself for data storage:

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  pgdata:

services:  
  (other services...)
  db:
    image: postgis/postgis:13-3.1-alpine
    environment:
       (some env vars...)
    ports: 
      - 5400:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

so it's the folder `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1248fdfe` which is taking a lot of disk space.

Comment: Use a tablespace

Comment: I see, thank you. But then I updated my question because all the PG data is dockerized, hence the pgdata directory is fully managed by docker itself in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`. So, do I instead need to specify a bind mount to a local folder? Or even creating two of them; one for the default tablespace, hosted on the host filesystem, e.g. on `/var/foo/` and the other bind mount placed elsewhere on a shared drive, e.g. in `/mnt/bar/` for the tablespace that is intended to hold the large table data? Maybe it's not the best idea, I cannot see what kind of issue could occur with such setup.